# Refrigerator Relay - Need replacement

Tags: relay

I have a broken Kegerator and need some insight. I'm familiar with electronic circuitry, but far from an expert. Everything (temp display, internal fan, change set temp) appears to be working as it should, except the compressor never kicks in. I believe I narrowed down the issue to a relay on the circuit board (picture included) that tells the compressor to turn on. I verified this by shorting the relay and then the compressor kicks in as it should.

[image: Kegerator Circuit Board - Relay]

**Few Questions:**

1. Does it sound like this relay is indeed the issue? If not, what else should I be doing?
2. It appears the relay is a SANYOU SMI-S-112LM : http://www.sanyourelay.ca/public/products/product_list_new.php?series=34&listby=0

Where can I buy one of these? All I can find online is bulk items. Is there perhaps a different manufacturer that I could use?

With a new relay and a little soldering work, I imagine I can get this up and running again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relay is similar to a [Panasonic JW1AFSN-DC12V](http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/power/catalog/mech_eng_jw.pdf) relay, cheaply available from various online sources (and likely of higher quality than Sanyou).

As the part number implies, the nominal coil voltage is 12V, so the relay expects to see about 12V across the coil to turn it on. As @markrages said, you need to check that first before mucking with replacing a PCB-mount relay- there are a number of reasons why the relay might not be pulling in, including a dead power supply, but based on your other comments about fans and display functioning, Mark's caution about a protection switch working (or not) could be the culprit.

Comment: Although this question might be off topic, I had the exact same question and I've spent hours on Digikey trying to find a drop in replacement. Thanks for the answer! To add some info from my end. I tapped the relay with a screw driver and it turned on. That isolated the issue to this relay and not the compressor relay. Also, this part is obsolete. Try [JW1AFSN-DC12V-F](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=RY%2fkUk5H9K2HOxEsVe9fkw%3d%3d)

Answer (score 1):

Measure the voltage on the relay coil.  If there is no voltage on the coil, the relay is probably OK, and it is not kicking in for other reasons.  For example, if the refrigerant has leaked out of the system, the relay will not activate, because running without refrigerant can damage the compressor.

If there *is* voltage at the relay coil and the compressor isn't turning on, then the relay is probably at fault.  To choose another relay, enter the specs of this one into a distributor's parametric search engine like Digi-Key.  Then look at the thumbnails for similar relays, and download datasheets to see if the footprints match.